# How can I see differences between two .sdf files?

Tags: database, comparison, sdf

I need a tool that show me the differences between two .sdf files.
Is there something I can download or do I have to write some code?

Comment: An SDF is an entire database.  What exactly are you looking for - schema differences?  Differences between similar rows in the same tables?  Rows that are missing from one but not the other?

Comment: i suppose i need to compare only the information schema... i have to know differences about number and name of tables and fields, type of fields and length

Comment: As you seem to have a specific database technology in mind, you should edit your question and change your tags to something more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of companies which make schema comparison tools for SQL Server (which I presume is what underlies your question).  For instance xSQL Software offers [xSQL Object](http://www.xsqlsoftware.com/Product/Sql_Schema_Compare.aspx), which is free for certain editions of SQL Server.  Red-Gate have [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm), which has a 14-day trial.

If you are looking for something FOSS, there is [Open DBDiff](http://www.codeplex.com/OpenDBiff).

Comment: SQL compare doesn't support sdf files :-(

Comment: the question was about sdf file , not server !

Answer (score -1):

If you are running on linux you can compare any two files, or directories for that matter, using the 'diff' command. The syntax is quite simple: 'diff item1 item2'. For more info use 'man diff' or check out [this link](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm).

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't use linux, i work on microsoft compact framework but tnx anyway!